# Georeferencing jpg via Gdal_translate output a GIS tif 15.5 times bigger

Tags: gdal, jpg, gdal-translate

**Given as input** a light 874kb jpg, I use `gdal_translate -a_ullr` ([source](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)) to reinject GIS georeferencing :

> **-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry :** 
>    Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file. This assigns georeferenced bounds to the output file,
>   ignoring what would have been derived from the source file

**My command** being:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr 67.0 37.5 99.0 05.0 ./color_hillsades.jpg ./color_hillsades.gis.tif
```

While the input is .874MB, the output is 13.5MB, or 15.51 times bigger.

[image]

**Why does it become so huge ?**

**What to do to keep it light ?**

Comment: My question's answer is mainly `-co COMPRESS=JPEG` which dived size by factor 10, the question [gdal_translate- why jpg compressed tif is 2 times greater than jpg file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76421/19460) have for answer `-co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR`, a tiny optimization by factor <2. Not the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [gdal_translate- why jpg compressed tif is 2 times greater than jpg file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76421/19460), I found the way :

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr 67.0 37.5 99.0 05.0 \
               -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \
               ./color_hillsades.jpg ./color_hillsades.gis.tif
```

Input is .888MB, output is a .898MB literally just 1% bigger for a georeferenced tif using JPEG compression. This .tif is loaded properly into Quantum GIS.

[image]